# Interpretation and some questions about NHK article

Tags: translation

> 異性**に**トイレの世話をしてもらっているお年寄りや、体と心の性が同じではない人など**から**男性や女性のトイレに入りにくいという意見が出ています。渋谷区は、駅や店などのトイレをみんなが使いやすくするために「トイレ基本方針」を決めました。
>
> 「トイレ基本方針」によると、男性のトイレと女性のトイレとは別に、どんな性の人も使うことができるトイレを作ります。目に障害がある人のために、壁とトイレは違う色にしてわかりやすくします。赤ちゃんのおむつをかえる
>   台や、服を脱ぐときに使う台は、もっと増やしていろいろなトイレに置きます

Could someone please break down what exactly the uses of に and から are here?

I am have a bit of trouble parsing the first paragraph in english and making understanding of it, my attempt is the following:

> To better help serve the opposite sex whom is aging （お年寄り), and also
>   those whos bodies and heart ( mabye this means mind actually?) do not
>   correspond directly with male or female and have trouble entering
>   standard gendered washrooms ( where does 意見が出ています come into play?).
>   For the purpose of making toilets easy to use "Toilet 基本 ( how would kihon be translate exactly here?) policy" was
>   put into plan in places like stores and train stations in shibuya.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 異性**に**トイレの世話をしてもらっているお年寄り

お年寄り means old people. This phrase is describing what kind of old people. 異性**に**トイレの世話をしてもらっている means "receiving toilet care **from/by** people of the opposite sex". So に here is **from/by**.

> ((異性にトイレの世話をしてもらっているお年寄り) や、(体と心の性が同じではない人) など)から男性や女性のトイレに入りにくいという意見が出ています。

The structure here is AやBからC意見が出ています。Opinions (of kind C) were expressed **from** people of kinds A and B.

Altogether:

> Old people who are receiving toilet care from members of the opposite sex and people whose physical gender and perceived gender differ gave opinions on the difficulty of entering men's and women's toilets.

This translation isn't entirely literal but I hope it's near enough for you to understand.

基本方針 would be basic policy.